# place cursor at the end of text in asp.net textbox using tab key

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net textbox which contains some predefined text by default.
when i move from one textbox to another using tabkey the cursor should place at the end of text. is it possible using jQuery or javascript ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this by using createTextRange of the texbox element.

you can refer this link [Set cursor in textbox](http://forums.asp.net/t/1087412.aspx/1)